# Enable ODP.Net performance counters Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Express Edition

Tags: .net, oracle, database-connection, windows-server-2016

How can I enable the ".Net Data Provider for Oracle" Performance Counters for my app?

I'm Using:

.Net 2.2.4
Oracle 11g
Windows 2016

Comment: did you  read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters

Comment: Yes of course.
This is the first thing i read

Comment: then you should be more concise in your question and provide where exactly the problem is and what did you try